# Cannot install Composer on Windows, OpenSSL error

Tags: php, openssl, composer-php

I am trying to install Composer on Windows 10. I downloaded the Composer-Setup.exe file from getcomposer.org. I ran it as Administrator. It found the correct version of PHP.exe in my PATH (C:\php\php.exe). I am not using a Proxy server. I click Install and I receive the following error message:

```
The Composer installer script was not successful [exit code 1].

OpenSSL failed with a 'certificate verify failed' error. This indicates a problem with the 
Certificate Authority file(s) on your system, which either cannot be found or may be out of date.

Script Output:
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
Failed to open stream: operation failed
```

I downloaded a new version of cacert.pem from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and placed it in C:\php. Then I updated php.ini with the following values:

```
[curl]
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an
; absolute path.
curl.cainfo=C:\php\cacert.pem

[openssl]
; The location of a Certificate Authority (CA) file on the local filesystem
; to use when verifying the identity of SSL/TLS peers. Most users should
; not specify a value for this directive as PHP will attempt to use the
; OS-managed cert stores in its absence. If specified, this value may still
; be overridden on a per-stream basis via the "cafile" SSL stream context
; option.
openssl.cafile=C:\php\cacert.pem
```

However, I am still receiving the error. What is causing the issue?